# Hyperledger Fabric: same TLS certs used by both Peers and parent organization? (referencing the Test Network)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In the Hyperledger Fabric [test network](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/test_network.html) registration script*, the TLS certs and keys are copied from the Peer's MSP to the parent Organization's MSP [(lines 63-71)](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/c8703df425a82d0283965191049d48195faba950/test-network/organizations/fabric-ca/registerEnroll.sh#L63-L71):

```
cp ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/tlscacerts/* ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
cp ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/signcerts/* ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
cp ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/keystore/* ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key


mkdir -p ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp/tlscacerts
cp ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/tlscacerts/* ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/ca.crt


mkdir -p ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca
cp ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/tlscacerts/* ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
```

Does this mean that the Organization uses the same TLS and certs and keys as the Peer?

If you add a second peer to the organization, would they (both peers and parent organization) all use the same TLS key+cert?

*This script is used when the Fabric-CA is used instead of cryptogen to generate the necessary certificates.

Answer (score 4):

Actually a peer organization MSP holds three elements

1. Organization Admin Certification under **/admincerts**
2. CA Certification or the certification of Certification Authority that will be in charge of issuing and signing all the certifications (peer, user ... ) under this organization under **/cacerts**
3. TLSCA Certification which is like CA Certification but used to sign all the TLS certification (peer, user ...) under this organization under **/tlscacerts**

Whereas a peer MSP holds five elements

1. The precedent three elements that represent the authorities that signed its own certifications ( /cacerts and /tlscacerts ) and the authority whith the right to perform operations ( /admincerts )
2. Its own public key which is under **/signcerts**
3. Its own private key that goes with its public key which is under **/keystore**

So to answer your question NO: organization and peer don't have the same MSP. Each peer has its own MSP( aka a couple public and private key which represent his unique identity  and the CA certs that signed it )
And the organization has only the CA certs that signed every node identity in that organization.

So when you create another peer under this Org ( with cryptogen tool for example ), this peer will hold in its MSP his own unique identity but the same CA certs then the other peer.

Comment: Hi Azza, thank you for your reply and explanation of the MSP contents.  I'm afraid my question may not have been worded clearly.  I'm not wondering if the organization and peer have the same MSP, but rather if they share the same TLS certificate in the Hyperledger Fabric Test-Network example.  If I understand the code correctly, the same TLS certificate is used by both.

I just updated my question to try to make it more clear.  (I'm also not sure if it is relevant, but I am looking at the code used when Fabric-CA, not cryptogen, is used to generate the certificates.)